# Oracle 12c - Column check constraint cannot reference other column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have to modify my table and I try do it as following:

```
ALTER TABLE projects
    MODIFY (
        id_proj NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_proj PRIMARY KEY,
        desc VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uk_proj UNIQUE,
        end_date CONSTRAINT chk_date CHECK(end_date > start_date),
        fund CHECK (fund > 0)
    );
```

And when I try execute this query I get an error:

> ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
>   02438. 00000 -  "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"
>   *Cause:    attempted to define a column check constraint that references
>              another column.
>   *Action:   define it as a table check constraint.

Additionally I want the column to accept values greater than 0 or NULL values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a syntax quirk. Do this:

```
ALTER TABLE projects
    MODIFY (
        id_proj NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_proj PRIMARY KEY,
        desc VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uk_proj UNIQUE,
        end_date DATE,  -- I'm guessing this is the type
        CONSTRAINT chk_date CHECK (end_date > start_date),
        fund CHECK (fund > 0)
    );
```

As the error suggests, you cannot have an in-line check constraint that references other columns.  You can still have a check constraint; it just needs to be declared by itself as a constraint.

While we are commenting:

- `desc` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL key word.  Use `descr` or spell the whole thing out, `description`.
- `CONSTRAINT uk_proj UNIQUE` seems verbose to me.  It can be replaced with a simple `UNIQUE`.  Admittedly, this doesn't allow you to name unique constraints.  Is that important for your database?
- The same is true of the primary key constraint.  (If you have a reason to name them, then leave it as it is; I just don't often find such a reason.)

Comment: @user - To what Gordon said, I would add that the same distinction between "in-line" constraints (only one column can be involved in the condition; the constraint is defined after the column name) and out-of-line constraints (which involve two or more columns and must be declared at the table level, after all column definitions) apply when you define the constraints in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. With pretty much the same syntax as Gordon has shown for `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Why behind DATE should I write a comma? Why can I write:
descr VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT ...
and I cannot write end_date DATE CONSTRAINT but I have to write end_date DATE, CONSTRAINT?

Comment: The reason for having to put a comma after `end_date DATE` is because in order to allow the constraint to reference any column on the table you must define the CHECK constraint as being on the table, not on the column. The comma separates the definition of the constraint from the definition of the column.